# How do I Create a new message draft using MIME format in MsGraph SDK 5.0

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

In version 3.0 I could do this by using GetHttpRequestMessage, but I cannot figure out how to access that now.

My old working Code was as follows:

```
var req = graphClient.Me.Messages
              .Request()
              .GetHttpRequestMessage();

req.Content = msgPost;//msgPost contains base64 mime.
req.Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post;

var result = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);
var resultJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```html
string testmail = @"RnJvbTogQWRlbGUgVmFuY2UgPEFkZWxlVkBjb250b3NvLmNvbT4KVG86IEFsZXggV2lsYmVyIDxB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"
            ;
            
var requestInformation = graphServiceClient.Users["user@d.com"].Messages.ToPostRequestInformation(new Message());
requestInformation.Headers.Clear();
requestInformation.SetStreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testmail)), "text/plain");
var result = await graphServiceClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync<Message>(requestInformation, Message.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```